# algorithm for generating grid of points

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've got array of coordinates in following schema (x,y):
`array = [[1,2],[1,5],[1,1],[2,2],[2,5],[2,1]]`

I would like to do some process to achieve effect:

`array1 = [[[1,2],[1,5],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,5],[2,1]]]; array2 = [[[2,2],[2,5],[2,1]]]`
and

`array1a = [[[1,2],[2,2]]]; array2a = [[[1,5],[2,5]]]; array3a=[[[1,1],[2,1]]]`

in other words I would like to get coordinates of all parallel and perpendicular lines.
I've came up with two double loops (one by x, and another by y) but maybe there is another faster(better) way

--
pseudo code:

> ```
>           for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>               for (var j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
>                   var x = points[i][j][0];
>                   var y = points[i][j][1];
>               };
>           };
>           for (var i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
>               for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
>                   var x = points[i][j][0] ;
>                   var y = points[i][j][1] ;
>               };
>           };
> ```

**EDIT**

OK, here's the situation:

[image]

I've got this kind of rectangle, I've got coordinates of points (red mark) as array:

`array = [[1,2],[1,5],[1,1],[2,2],[2,5],[2,1]]`

and I want to make antoher array which will be like this:

`array1 = [[[1,2],[1,5],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,5],[2,1]]]`

in above array there are coordinates of points thats one of green line containts. Those lines are parallel or perpendicular lines to sides of rectangle.

Comment: I can see that these are 2D coordinates, but where do the "lines" come in? And what do these for loops achieve except extracting the last point in the last array in a very inefficient way?

Comment: @Thomas in all of subarrays (ie. `[[1,2],[1,5],[1,1]]`) are coordinates of lines that are parallels or normal to min and max coordinates of this whole dataSet. I consider only 2D plane, and later I'm using this subarrays as argument to function which draw line by them.

Comment: @Krystian I'm not sure if I understand the points you are trying to generate. Perhaps a little drawing or slightly more/more clear explanation of the new points you're trying to generate would help.

Comment: How does `[[1,2],[1,5],[1,1]]` define lines? Typically, three points would define a triangle. Your question makes no sense. You want "parallel and perpendicular lines". Parallel and perpendicular to what?

Comment: Lets see.To extract only horizontal and vertical lines you have to put a condition. Every line (2 or more points) must have points which have the same X (or) Y components. Otherwise it is a diagonal. If more than 2 points find all points which have that same component. If same X --> line is vertical. If same Y--> line is horizontal. Note: If you intend to include diagonal and angular lines, you have to use angles. Use the tangent angle (not cos/sin) to worth with 0/360° and not only 0/180°.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the points by X coordinate and then group them together by X coordinate, each group is a set of points on a vertical line.

Similarly, if you sort the points by Y coordinate and then group them together by Y coordinate, each group is a set of points on a horizontal line.

If this sounds simplistic, I apologize. But your initial description and the added diagram with your further explanation leads me to believe that it's what you're asking for.

Comment: thank you for answer, you have right, I have to sort points by coordinates. But try to look at my source data-set if I would like to sort them and then extract by method you suggest I will get 2 double loops through the data Set (as is shown in my question). And I would like to avoid it or change the algorithm to simplify this task.

Comment: @Krystian: To sort the points, call the Javascript `sort` function. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp for examples. You can tell it how to compare the points.